# Assign a value to different variable based on a certain condition

Tags: javascript

How can I assign a value to different variable based on a certain condition?

For example, if now the variable `a` is true, then I want to assign the string "Hello" to the variable `b`, but not the variable `c`.

But if now the variable `a` is not true, then I hope the string "Hello" could be assigned to the variable `c`, but not the variable `b`.

Is there a way to assign a value to different variable based on a certain condition in Javascript?

Like this:

```js
var a = true;
var b, c;
((a) ? b : c) = "Hello";
console.log(b); //This should output "Hello"
console.log(c); //This should output `undefined`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an if... else statement.

```js
var a = true;
var b, c;
if (a) {
  b = "Hello";
} else {
  c = "Hello";
}
console.log(b); //This should output "Hello"
console.log(c); //This should output `undefined`
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot choose the target of an assignment as an expression<sup>1</sup>. You should just write

```
if (a) {
    b = "Hello";
} else {
    c = "Hello";
}
```

If you don't want to duplicate the `"Hello"` expression that constructs the variable, put it in a temporary variable. However it is really rare that you need to assign to different variables. Consider calling a function instead which has the result you want based on your condition:

```
function chooseOrder(x) {
    return a ? [x, undefined] : [undefined, x];
}
;[b, c] = chooseOrder("Hello");
```

---

1: well, there's always an exception. We could for example use setter properties, and dynamically choose the object whose property is assigned:

```
(a
  ? {set value(v) { b = v; }}
  : {set value(v) { c = v; }}
).value = "Hello";
```

but this really should be considered a trick with a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose the target of an assignment using an expression. An `if() ... else` is needed for what you're trying to do.

```js
var a = true;
var b, c;
if(a)
  b = "Hello";
else
  c = "Hello";
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```